# what is different between CloudWatch(Log) and Db?

Tags: database, logging, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

On Aws, cloudwatch can monitor resources, logs of ec2 applications...

1. what is different between cloudwatch(log) and db?
2. When to use log rather than db?
3. What is advantage cloudwatch(log) vs db ?

Just like this example said
[Amazon Web Service CloudWatch custom metrics with dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505579/amazon-web-service-cloudwatch-custom-metrics-with-dimensions)

I add two Dimensions as follows
1. Name: Male, Count: 50
2. Name: Female, Count: 40

This information, such like  1. Name: Male, Count: 50 2. Name: Female, Count: 40, all can store in DB.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the above result, if your dimension data is like this.

> Dimensions: RoomName=room1, Sex=Male, Unit: Count, Timestamp:
>   2016-10-31T12:30:00Z, Value: 105
>
> Dimensions: RoomName=room1, Sex=Female, Unit: Count, Timestamp:
>   2016-10-31T12:31:00Z, Value: 115
>
> Dimensions: RoomName=room2, Sex=Male,  Unit: Count, Timestamp:
>   2016-10-31T12:32:00Z, Value: 95
>
> Dimensions: RoomName=room2, Sex=Female, Unit: Count, Timestamp:
>   2016-10-31T12:33:00Z, Value: 97

If the data point is sent as 90 without sex attribute (Male or Female), you can't get the fine grained information (count by sex) in the result.

[Cloudwatch dimension](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html#Dimension)

AWS CloudWatch Logs is a service which is integrated with other services like EC2, CloudTrail etc. You can get data from these services and monitor them for any errors, events etc.

> Amazon CloudWatch Logs can be used to monitor, store, and access your
>   log files from Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instances,
>   AWS CloudTrail, Route 53, and other sources. You can then retrieve the
>   associated log data from CloudWatch Logs.

[CloudWatch logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/WhatIsCloudWatchLogs.html)

Comment: I not ask how to use Cloudwatch dimension and CloudWatch logs. I ask three questions.1. what is different between cloudwatch(log) and db?
2. When to use log rather than db?
3. What is advantage cloudwatch(log) vs db ?